# Is it possible to specify two limit values(from, offset) in one Phalcon\Mvc\Model::find() method?

Tags: php, phalcon

For a moment i found following example:

```
 $robots = Robots::find(array("limit" => 100));
```

Is it possible to define two values for limit, "from" and "offset"?
In Zend Framework it was possible with Db adapter function, that looked like this:

```
 $db->select()->limit($from, $offset)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use PHQL which supports the `OFFSET` like so (in a controller):

```
$sql     = 'SELECT * FROM Robots LIMIT 100 OFFSET 10';
$stmt    = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($sql)
$results = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I preferred not to use raw queries here.. Phalcon\Mvc\Model gives very good abstraction layer here. But anyway ur answer is correct, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$collection = Model::find(array(
    "limit" => array('number' => $from, 'offset' => $offset)
));
```

Comment: Works fine on version 1.3.2, thanks. If you need to paginate using $params['limit'] and $params['page'] (starting at page #1), you can do the following: $params['limit'] = array('number' => $params['limit'], 'offset' => ($params['page'] - 1) * $params['limit']); unset($params['page']);

Answer (score 1):

limit parameter can not only accept int values.
this example would work too:

```
$offset = 20;
$from = 10;
$collection = Model::find(array("limit" => $from . ',' . $offset));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass another element called offset and specify the value in it,refer to the given below example:

$orders=Orders::find(array(
            `"order"` => "id DESC",
            `"limit"` => 10,
            `"offset"` => 0
          ));

You may refer to following link for detailed information:

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html

Answer (score -1):

You can make your query pretty customizable doing this:

```
    <?php
    $notifications = \UserNotification::find([
        "user_id = :user_id: ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5",
            "bind" => [
            "user_id" => 1
         ]
    ]);
```